# Integer division in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, select, sqldatatypes

I have a MySQL table which has a `product_id` field (big integer)

> `1102330008`
>   `1102330025`
>   `1102330070`
>   `1103010009`
>   `1103010010`
>   `1103020006`
>   ...

I want to select rows which have `product_id = 110301****`. I tried to use this query:

```
SELECT * FROM `product` WHERE (product_id/10000)=110301
```

but it does not return any values with this message:

> `MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows). ( Query took 0.0005 sec )`

Comment: Why are you using division and not `BETWEEN` or `< >` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-indexes.html) says that `LIKE` also uses indexes so I think you could also use:

```
SELECT *
FROM `product`
WHERE product_id LIKE '110301____' -- four undersores as biziclop suggested
```

**edit:** to fix your own query you would need to use `FLOOR()` ([documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_floor)) because it results something like:

```
1103010006 / 10000
```

which results 110301,0006 and it's not equal to `110301`

Comment: I would use `LIKE '110301____'` to avoid matching with `1103010`, etc.

Comment: The question is how MySQL uses indexes when `LIKE`ing against numeric fields.

Answer (score 45):

Use the [`DIV` operator](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/arithmetic-functions.html#operator_div).

```
mysql> SELECT 5 DIV 2;
    -> 2
```

> Integer division. Similar to FLOOR(), but is safe with BIGINT values. Incorrect results may occur for noninteger operands that exceed BIGINT range.

Comment: not like FLOOR(), but TRUNCATE(). For example: `select -5 div 2, floor(-5 / 2);` you'll get `-2, -3`

Answer (score 9):

```
SELECT *
FROM product
WHERE product_id BETWEEN 1103010000
                     AND 1103019999
```

If you want to create your query in PHP, then you can construct your query like

```
$sql = "
    SELECT *
    FROM product
    WHERE product_id BETWEEN {$product_id_range}0000
                         AND {$product_id_range}9999  
";
```

Comment: I have a php variable that holds the '110301' value, so I dont want to do math and want to gain a query which relies on '110301' not '1103010000' or '1103019999'

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT * 
  FROM `product` 
 WHERE `product_id` >= 1103010000 
   AND `product_id` <= 1103019999
```

Comment: I didn't research your query but it could be a math problem. Even so, it is a more complicated way to do it then the solutions provided here. Always keep things as simple as possible.

Comment: @bijibuji I think the answer I posted would address the reason the original solution does not work.

Comment: @John Conde: I have a php variable that holds the '110301' value, so I dont want to do math and want to gain a query which relies on '110301' not '1103010000' or '1103019999'

Answer (score 3):

You can use the MySQL Integer division operator [DIV](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/arithmetic-functions.html#operator_div) like this:

```
SELECT * FROM `product` WHERE (product_id DIV 10000)=110301
```

Also safe for BIGINT.

Answer (score 1):

[MYSQL Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/arithmetic-functions.html), I think, explains why this occurs;

> A division is calculated with BIGINT arithmetic only if performed in a
>   context where its result is converted to an integer.

So if you convert the result to an integer, it may work.

**Edit:**
Try

```
SELECT * FROM `product` WHERE cast((product_id/10000) as int) = 110301
```

Comment: Thanks! but how can I convert the result to integer? which result?